# Ordinary Differential equation question help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So i saw a question on ODE online and it stated that:

> For the given Differential equation $y'=-2x+3y-5$ , a solution comes in the form $y(x)=mx+b$.

Then the instructor proceeded to state that if y(x) is a solution it needs to be true for all x's, im really confused in that last line "true for all x's" what does that mean.

Answer (score 1):

When you substitute back into the differential equation you get $m=(3m-2)x+3b-5$. You may have an instinct to solve the resulting equation for $x$, getting $x=\frac{m+5-3b}{3m-2}$. However that is how you solve an algebraic equation for a number, not a function equation (such as a differential equation) for a function. Stating that two functions are equal means they take the same output for every input. A functional (or differential) equation must be satisfied not just at a single $x$ value, but rather for all $x$ values. A polynomial equation can be solved for isolated $x$ values which satisfy it (for example by using the quadratic formula). But two polynomials can only be equal for all $x$ if all their coefficients match.

For the equation in question this can only happen if the linear terms and constant terms have the same coefficient. In other words $3m-2=0$ and $3b-5=m$, giving $y=2x/3+17/9$ as your answer, a function of $x$ which satisfies the functional equation at every $x$ value.

Answer (score 0):

When solving ordinary differential equations your unknown is a function $y(x)$, so if it is a solution it must satisfy the differential equation for all $x$. This 'for all x' part sometimes is omitted in the statement of the differential equation, but implicitly assumed.